# Change dots from first line to the second line (List of Tables)

Tags: table-of-contents, vertical-alignment

I want to change the dot(.....) from first line to the second line (i.e. at end). see figure [image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please post the LaTeX code itself, not an image of the code.

Comment: Thank you actually its from thesis file, so whole coding is difficult to share thats why i just share the relevant data in image.

Comment: Rather than posting an image it is much easier to help you if post a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). That is, a minimal piece, that compiles (so it has a `\documentclass` statement et), and demonstrates your problem. A MWE makes it much easier for people to help you are they can cut-and-paste from the code you supply. As it is not possible to copy-and-paste from screenshots they are less helpful, which means that people are less likely to help you.

Answer (score 2):

This too long for a comment, which is what is more than an answer.

The standard classes (`book`, `report`, `article`) do what you want.

```
% lotprob.tex  SE 558714
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\listoftables

\begin{table}
\centering A TABLE
\caption{This is a long caption that takes more than one line when printed in the LOT}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

You have done something different but have not provided an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}` like the one above) exhibiting your problem that we can compile and maybe help you.